# i want to fetch records from excel using c++ and want to control the output with particular column data say book id

Tags: c++, excel, c++-cli

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name1;
    int i=2;
    int d1=i;
    string name2="c++programming";
    string author_name1="nileshchanglani";
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("my excel.xls");
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    myfile<<i<< "\t"<<name2<<"\t"<<author_name1<<endl;

    myfile.close();

  myfile.open("my excel.csv");
  for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
 myfile<<i<<","<<name2<<","<<author_name1<<endl;
}
  myfile.close();
   ifstream myfile1;
   myfile1.open("my excel.xls");
 int bookid;

 string name,author_name;
  while(myfile1 >> bookid >> name2>> author_name)
  if(bookid==3)
  cout<<bookid<<"     "<<name2<<"       "<<author_name<<endl;
(myfile1>>bookid>>name2>>author_name);
cout<<bookid<<"     "<<name2<<"       "<<author_name<<endl;

}
```

i am trying to columns from excel sheet into variable id name2 and author name and trying to control the output with id number coding runnig fine until there are no spaces in author name and book name but it give me only 1  record output if there are spaces in book name and author name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse excel you will better search for CVS(Comma Separated Value) parsers for example

https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser

Excel has a same format. If you open the excel file with text editor you will see data separated with "," or ";".

Comment: problem is code is running fine until only if i pass book name or author name without spaces